# Redirecting URL to different web app in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I am running tomcat 6.0, and am having trouble configuring it to do what I want...

I have two web apps, call them X and Y, deployed as X.war and Y.war.  Each has a servlet called blah.

So I can access them like so:
http://server/X/blah
http://server/Y/blah

What I want to do is pretend they are one web application Z, and be able to do this:

http://server/Z/X/blah    -->  as if I'd gone to http://server/X/blah

http://server/Z/Y/blah    -->  as if I'd gone to http://server/Y/blah

So I changed the (catalina_home)/conf/Catalina/localhost/X.xml as follows:
< context override="true" path="/Z/X" reloadable="false" >

However that didn't work out; when going to http://server/Z/X/blah I get "The requested resource (/Z/X/blah) is not available."

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

An alternate way to do this would be to setup tomcat behind apache via ajp. Then, use mod_proxy_ajp to map the http://server/Z/ to ajp://server/ instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you add the `Context` within `server.xml` it will work as you want.

```
<Context docBase="x" path="/z/x" reloadable="true"  />
```

This approach is not recommended by the Tomcat docs, since any changes to `server.xml` means restarting the server disturbing all the web apps.

But, on the flip side, the practice of keeping this as you want in `Catalina_Home/conf/Catalina/localhost/context.xml` has some unreliabilities as others have reported.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032773/why-does-tomcat-replace-context-xml-on-redeploy and

[Why does tomcat like deleting my context.xml file?](https://serverfault.com/q/192784/37747)

Comment: Hi, Can you check out this question regarding redirection : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33388020/apache-tomcat-permanent-redirect-not-working